# ISBLANK(...) = FALSE even thought the cell is blank in google sheet

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, formula, nonblank

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have 2 tables, 3rd column for `Table 1` is `Value 1` and 3rd column for `Table 2` is `Value 2`. I combined these 2 tables by expanding both tables first so that all the columns are aligned as shown in the screenshot above (Column E to Column H).

The formula in all the yellow cells are:

Cell E4 : `=QUERY(A4:C10,"Select A,B,C,' ' label ' ' 'Value 2' ")`

Cell E12 : `=QUERY(A12:C20,"Select A,B,' ',C label ' ' 'Value 1' ")`

Cell K7 : `=QUERY({E5:H10;E13:H17},"Select * where Col1 is not null",0)`

Cell P7 : `=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(M7:M12),100,M7:M12))`

In column P, I want to return `100` as `Value 1` if the cells in Column M is blank. So by right I should get `2,34,55,100,100,100` in column P but right now the formula still return 3 blank cells.

I suspect that is because the `QUERY` function that I used before which make the cell is not blank although it seems like still a blank cell. May I know is there any trick that I can use to find the blank cells in column M and column N (preferably don't touch the QUERY formula) since `ISBLANK()` is not working in this case?

Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

### Edited

[image]

Comment: In your case, these cells are not empty. They contain a space character, which you yourself add to the data in the preparatory queries. You can replace `ISBLANK(M7:M12)` with `(M7:M12= ' ')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

makes sense. you cant use ISBLANK because cell is not blank. remember that QUERY inserted an empty space.

try:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(TRIM(M7:M12)), 100, M7:M12))`

ISBLANK is so sensitive that it will detect even residue from TRIM

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TRIM(M7:M12)="", 100, M7:M12))
```

Comment: Hi player0, i tried your formula, but it seems like not working as well.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bcepGasbl90oNoRHiwCM5a3xYbLlxr7EKb2K6d6fmhU/edit#gid=753784960